# Loading/calling csHtml from .JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using MVC 4, trying to load the .csHtml file from .JS file but i am keeping get the error "not found"
is there any other way i can work around?

here is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-sidebar').on('click', function () {
        $('div#main').toggleClass('sidebar-show');
        setTimeout(MessagesMenuWidth, 250);
    });
    var ajax_url = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
        ajax_url = 'Views/Home/index.cshtml'; //<<<< when the browser load i get the msg "not found" 
    }
     ................
     ................
```

Comment: You don't want the web server serving .cshtml files -- are you trying to load the view at `/Home/Index`?

Comment: thats is correct i am trying to load the view at /home/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to get the URL using the MVC routing system.  Use the URL helper method [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to get the URL for a given controller/action:

```
if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
    ajax_url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
}
```

**Edit**

Since this snippet of Javascript is not in a Razor file, you'll have to get the URL another way.  You could just hard code it:

```
if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
    ajax_url = '/Home/Index';
}
```

This will work locally, but be aware that it will not be the correct URL if your site is ever hosted under a sub-path like `http://www.server.com/somepath/`.  I would recommend re-organizing so that you can still use the URL helper -- either embed your Javascript in a Razor file, or inject the URL into a global variable from Razor like this:

```
(window.MyGlobalObjects || (window.MyGlobalObjects = {})).HomeUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
```

Make sure to place the above line before loading the external JS file.  That way you should be able to access the URL as a variable:

```
if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
    ajax_url = window.MyGlobalObjects.HomeUrl;
}
```

---

Note that you would never want your web server serving a pre-compiled .cshtml file -- that's a pre-compiled file that is not useful on the client (and also might contain sensitive info that you wouldn't want exposed).

Comment: still getting this same error and at run time this url is generating http://localhost:63049/Home/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22Home%22)

Comment: @AbuHamzah See my updated answer. I was assuming that your JS code was embedded in a Razor file, but apparently it is a standalone .js.